# Removing stale reported metric data from opentelemetry js prometheus exporter

Tags: prometheus, grafana, open-telemetry

I am attempting to set-up the [Grafana Geomap](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/geomap/) to display the location of moving units.  I am using the [OpenTelemetry JS](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js) npm package with the [Prometheus Exporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus).  The problem I am running into is removing 'stale' metrics from being continuously reported.  I can not remove callback functions that have been pulled by the metrics endpoint.

I created a metrics controller class that creates the metrics from the meter, creates an object to hold the callback functions, and sets a timeout to cleanup old callbacks.

```
export class MetricsController {
  constructor(meter) {
    this.callbacks = {};
    this.reportingMetrics = ["metric1", "metric2", "location", "latitude", "longitude"];
    this.metrics = this.createMetrics(meter);

    setTimeout(this.cleanupMetrics.bind(this), 10000);
  }
  createMetrics(meter) {
    const metrics = {};
    for (const metric of this.reportingMetrics) {
      metrics[metric] = meter.createObservableGauge(
        "unit_" + metric,
        {
          description: "unit " + metric
        }
      );
    }
    return metrics;

  }
  recordMetrics(incomingMetrics) {
    if (!this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId])
      this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId] = {};

    this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId].timestamp = new Date();

    for (const metric of this.reportingMetrics) {
      if (this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId][metric]) {
        this.metrics[metric].removeCallback(
          this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId][metric]
        );
        delete this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId][metric];
      }
      if (metric == "location") {
        this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId][metric] = (observableResult) => {
          observableResult.observe(1, {
            key: incomingMetrics.unitId,
            latitude: incomingMetrics.latitude,
            longitude: incomingMetrics.longitude,
            name: incomingMetrics.unitId
          });
        };
      } else {
        this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId][metric] = (observableResult) => {
          observableResult.observe(incomingMetrics[metric], {
            unit: incomingMetrics.unitId
          });
        };
      }
      this.metrics[metric].addCallback(
        this.callbacks[incomingMetrics.unitId][metric]
      );
    }
  }
  cleanupMetrics() {
    for (const unit of Object.keys(this.callbacks)) {
      if (
        Date.now() - this.callbacks[unit].timestamp <=
        process.env.METRICS_TIMEOUT_MINUTES * 60 * 1000
      ) {
        for (const metric of this.reportingMetrics) {
          this.metrics[metric].removeCallback(this.callbacks[unit][metric]);
        }
        delete this.callbacks[unit];
      }
    }
    setTimeout(this.cleanupMetrics.bind(this), 10000);
  }
}
```

This works almost the way I expected, however there is one issue.  If a metric is reported to the metrics endpoint, I can't remove the callback function anymore.  It will continue reporting it forever.  Is there a way to clean up this stale data?  It's very important for the location because every new lat/lon creates a new metric since they are being attached as labels.  I'm attaching the lat/lon as labels so I can display them on the geomap, but maybe there is a better way to do that?

This also means I won't know when units are off since their metrics will be keep being reported by the exporter.  The only method I could find to purge data was this removeCallback function but I might have missed something, I am very new to prometheus/metrics so I also might just be thinking about this incorrectly.  I'd love it if the exporter just purged the metrics after each scrape, then I wouldn't even need this controller.

Comment: If I understand what you are doing correctly, you approach is deeply wrong. Prometheus' metric must not contain label with latitude and longitude. This will result in extreme resources usage by Prometheus, because every unique labels set results in a unique time series. You simply ballooning up cardinality for no apparent reason.

Comment: If all you want is to use those coordinates at map - simply use dedicated latitude and longitude metrics and join them in Grafana using transformations (probably Merge, or maybe Join by field)

Comment: Thank you markalex,  I was worried that exporting the lat/lon as labels wasn't correct but it seemed the easiest way to get the map working.  I'll try working with the merge/join for the separate lat/lon metrics.  Still need to figure out how to purge the old data though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with library you are trying to use (nor I'm an expert in js/ts), but your code seems overly complicated. I believe simple transformation of array of values into set of metrics should be more straightforward.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).